# Al iniciar Spring boot se crea una nueva tabla

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Al iniciar Spring boot me crea automaticamente una tabla , no entiendo el por que , no deberia crearse nada , excepto cuando inserta un valor , entonces ahi se deberia crear el codigo de matricula

clase matricula

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Matricula {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_mat_seq")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cod_mat_seq", 
    strategy = "com.proyectomvc.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
    parameters = {
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "3"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = 
"COD_MAT"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") 
})
private String codMatricula;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "matricula", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Alumno Alumno;

public Matricula() {
}

public Matricula(String codMatricula,Alumno alumno) {
    this.codMatricula = codMatricula;
    Alumno = alumno;
}

public String getCodMatricula() {
    return codMatricula;
}

public void setCodMatricula(String codMatricula) {
    this.codMatricula = codMatricula;
}

public Alumno getAlumno() {
    return Alumno;
}

public void setAlumno(Alumno alumno) {
    Alumno = alumno;
}


}
```

clase StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator para generar el código automaticamente

```
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
private String valuePrefix;

public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
private String numberFormat;

@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
        Object object) throws HibernateException {
    return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
}

@Override
public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
    
    super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
    
    valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
            params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
    numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
            params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
 }


}
```

[image: base de datos]

Comment: Como que no debería crearse nada??? Spring por defecto crea las tablas que necesite al lanzar la aplicación

Comment: y por que crea el cod_mat_seq ?, no lo entiendo

Comment: `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_mat_seq"` Si creas una secuencia personalizada, necesita una tabla donde guardarla. Imagínate que lanzas tu aplicación, generas 100 filas en la tabla con tus secuencias personalizas "sec-1" a "sec-100" ... luego da un error no controlado y la aplicación se detiene... la relanzas y vuelves a empezar en "sec-1"???? Pues no es lo correcto, por eso para persistirla necesitas una tabla donde ir guardando la información para la secuencia personalizada

Comment: yo lo que estoy buscando es que se genere una secuencia en la primary key de matricula no en otra tabla...

Comment: Pero has especificado un generador propio. Cómo pretendes guardar la información de esa secuencia??? Imagínate que insertas 10 filas, llegas a la key "seq-10"... luego en otro momento borras la "seq-2", al día siguiente quieres insertar una nueva... cuál es?? Como hay 9 elementos, insertas otra "seq-10" y tienes una primary key repetida??? Si usas una secuencia personalizada, spring te crea una tabla para almacenar los datos de la secuencia y así saber cómo debe asignarlas! Es solo una tabla auxiliar, la secuencia será tu primary key, pero **necesita** saber qué tiene que darte en cada momento

Comment: la primary key también se referencia en esa tabla auxiliar?

Comment: ¿Cual base de datos estas utilizando?